# Restrict options to a ChoiceField Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

thanks for your time:
i'd like to know if there is a way to restrict an option on a choicefield if other field starts with a letter 'A':
basically i want to don't let the user set the choice (2, 'GATO') on Animal.tipo if his name starts with letter 'a' on People.nome

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator



class People(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    birthday_date = models.DateTimeField()
    cpf = models.CharField(max_length=11, validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.nome)

class Animal(models.Model):
    field_choices = [
        (1, 'CACHORRO'),
        (2, 'GATO'),
        (3, 'OUTRO'),
    ]
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo = models.IntegerField(choices=field_choices)
    custo = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.pessoa, self.name)

    def cant_have_cat(self):
        self.maiusculo = self.pessoa.upper
        if self.maiusculo[0] == 'A':
            self.tipo != 2
```

Comment: Do you want those choices to not even be displayed?  Or do you want them to be displayed, but the form should reject them?

Comment: don't matter can be both ways but just the choice (2, GATO) can't be chosen

Comment: It's a lot simpler to display all the choices and then reject the unwanted ones if chosen.  You can do that in the form `clean()` method.

Comment: them the field will be cleanned before the POST request? or will raise an error?